# Programming with Macbook Pro, and map mouse left click to keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am very new to Mac. When programming with eclipse or any other application, is it possible to map mouse left click to keyboard ?

Comment: Do you mean that while using eclipse, you would like to be able to press a key and have Eclipse treat that as a left click, or do you mean that you would like to write a program using Eclipse, and have *that program* treat a given key as a left click when running *that program*?

Comment: Maybe set up a shortcut bind to leftclick?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to do what you are asking in Eclipse (as an IDE). If you are trying to do this in an app that you are creating you could map certain key press actions to fire mouse events.

If this is just for your local mac use, you might look at the Mac keyboard/mouse config and see if you can change the mapping there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, i  mean that this could work for all applications, whole OS. I had a look to universal accessibility options, but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you're new to the mac:

You can configure the trackpad to accept clicks directly (that is, tapping on the pad is the equivalent of clicking the button).  In that way, left-clicks can be performed either by clicking the trackpad button or by tapping the trackpad itself.

Right-clicks are, in Mac-land, sometimes represented by control-clicks (which gets hairy when the application is programmed to accept control-clicks, but that's a whole 'nother story...)  So you can hold the control key and click the trackpad button, or tap the trackpad, to get a right-click.  You can further configure the trackpad to accept two-finger taps on the trackpad as right-clicks (no control key needed); also, two-finger drags can scroll, like a scroll wheel.